# cx_Oracle - "expecting None or a string"

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am on the following cx_Oracle version

```
>>> cx_Oracle.version
'5.0.3'
```

I am getting this exception in executing a query

"expecting None or a string"

The query is being executed this way

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM APP_STORE WHERE STORE=:STORE %s" %(order_clause),{'STORE':STORE})
```

What could be the reason? Similar queries executed earlier in the flow work fine but this one does not.

Appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You are building your cursor incorrectly. Since you pass a dictionary, you much first prepare your query:

```
cursor.prepare("SELECT * FROM APP_STORE WHERE STORE=:STORE %s" %(order_clause))
```

Then you execute it and pass `None` as the first parameter.

```
results = cursor.execute(None, {'STORE':STORE})
```

If you wish to change the `STORE` parameter and run the query again, all you need to do now is modify the dictionary and rerun the `execute` statement. `prepare`ing it again is not needed.

More information can be found at the [Oracle+Python Querying best practices documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html). The information I provided, above, is in the "Bind Variable Patterns" section (no direct link seems to be available)